# PHP DOMNodeList Error: Works in dev but not in production

Tags: php, dom

I have the below piece of code that is working fine on my local development server as it should but not on production. My local development environment is using `PHP 5.6.12` and my production server using `PHP 5.4.36`, I'm getting the below error in the production logs, no errors in the local development logs.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /public_html/dev_host/Jobs.php on line 111
```

**Line 110 - 113:**

```
$productRaw = $data->getElementsByTagName('a');
$productId = $this->parseProductId($productRaw[0]->attributes[0]->nodeValue);
$productAttributes = (array) json_decode($productRaw[0]->attributes[2]->nodeValue);
$productDetails = $this->parseProductDetails($productAttributes['name']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to treat `DOMNodeList` as an array was added in PHP 5.6.3.

Earlier than PHP 5.6.3, you will have to use `$productRaw->item(0);` instead of `$productRaw[0]`.

This was [bug #67949](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67949) and listed in the [5.6.3 changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.3), but otherwise appears to be undocumented.